# why doesn't rvm show me a special promtpt like virtualenv

Tags: rvm

I just installed RVM on Ubuntu 11.04,and I am comparing it with Python's virtualenv.

When I activate virtualenv it changes the prompt (on my Ubuntu system), so I know exactly which environment is active in that terminal. RVM on the other hand does not seem to do that. RVM also does not seem to need any activation.

Am I missing something here, or is this the way rvm works by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it by yourself:

```
PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1"
```

more details here: https://rvm.io/workflow/prompt/

or you could build your own prompt like I do:
https://github.com/mpapis/home_dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc#L17 +
https://github.com/mpapis/home_dotfiles/blob/master/.functions#L156-L160